# Stored procedure to return table names that match pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to write a stored procedure in MariaDB/MySQL that will return table names, if any, within the schema that matches a pattern provided by the parameters. Guessing this is accomplished by querying the information_schema table, but any advice and example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple select like this:

```sql
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%m%' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql';
```

Here we select all tables from schema `mysql` that contain `m` in the name.

Surprisingly, you can access this information even on demo sites. Here is demo at [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s2IXwYJ4).

Answer (score 0):

This query does what you want, if by pattern-matching you mean SQL's LIKE-style matching.

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
  AND TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
  AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '%pattern%';
```

Pretty straightforward. You *could* put this into a stored procedure. Or not. Depending on the complexity of software deployment you're looking for.